# Apply the action only to this element on the page

Tags: jquery, function, this, each

Please tell me how to bind the `displayCount` function to the current `filter_item`? All that in `$('.filter_item').each(function() {` it works correctly, but `function displayCount() {` runs for all `filter_item` on the page.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    
    var count = 0;
    
    $('.filter_item').each(function() {
        
        count = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input:checked').length;
        displayCount();  
        
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input').bind('click' , function(e, a) {   
            if (this.checked) {
                count += a ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                count += a ? 1 : -1;
            }
            displayCount();
        });
        
    });
    
    function displayCount() {
        if (count == 0) {
            $('.count').hide();
            } else {
            $('.count').show();
            $('.count').text(count);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you show your html code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.count').hide();
```

Selects each element in the document which has the class count. So yes it will change every entry. If you want to change only the one you get by each you need to transfer $(this) to your displayCount() function

```
 function displayCount(element) {
    if (count == 0) {
        element.hide();
        } else {
        element.show().text(count);
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
$('.filter_item').each(function() {
    
    var element = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input:checked');
    count = element.length;
    displayCount(element);  
    
    ....
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't really understand it yet, but it didn't seem to help. I need to bind the ```displayCount``` function to each ```.filter_item``` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone will need)

```
jQuery(function($) {

    
    $('.filter_item').each(function() {
        let that = this;
        let count = 0;
        count = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input:checked').length;
        displayCount.call(that, count);  
        
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox].jet-checkboxes-list__input').bind('click' , function(e, a) {  
            if (this.checked) {
                count += a ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                count += a ? 1 : -1;
            }
            displayCount.call(that, count);
        });
    });
    
    function displayCount(count) {
        if (count == 0) {
            $('.count', this).hide();
            } else {
            $('.count', this).show().text(count);
        }
    }
});
```